# QGIS - .OSM Attributes Table not allowing editing

Tags: qgis

I was sent an .osm file that has both shape/polygon/point layers in, but when I open up the attributes table to one of the layers

there is no way of selecting the toggle edit mode

as it is greyed out

[image]

Is there a way to turn the function back on?

Answer (score 1):

I think I have solved this issue, by copying each layer individually and saving as a new shapefile within my QGIS directory

Comment: I'd save it out to geopackage, but yes, pbf/osm are not currently directly editable in QGIS.